# Using pandas.DataFrame.at() in a for loop

Tags: python, list, pandas, for-loop, dataframe

pandas DataFrame I'm starting with:

[image: pandas DataFrame I'm starting with]

pandas DataFrame I'm trying to build:

[image: pandas DataFrame I'm trying to build]

I'm very new to computer science so I wasn't quite sure how to word my question without providing images. Basically, I want to build a pandas DataFrame with one row that has columns with column names -3 to 3 and the values below are the maximum absolute values of the second column from the first pandas DataFrame in relation to the first column from the first pandas DataFrame.

I also have the same data in a list a shown here:

[image: I also have the same data in a list a shown here]

Here is what I've tried but I keep getting an error:

[image: Here is what I've tried but I keep getting an error]

Comment: shouldn't your values of the resulting dataframe have `-1` for '1' and '2'?

Comment: oops, I meant to say that for those,  the result I want is the most negative number. I'll edit the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution. Looping over the dataframe to get what you want seems overkill

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[-1,1],[-2,2],[-2,1],[-2,2],[-1,6],[-1,2],[-1,1],[1,-2],[2,-2],[1,-2],[2,-1],[6,-1],[2,-1],[1,-1]])
max = df.groupby(0)[1].max()
x = dict()
for i in range(-3,4):
    try:
        if y[i] < 0:
            x[i] = z[i]
        else:
            x[i] = y[i]
    except KeyError:
        x[i] = 0
x = pd.DataFrame(x, index = [0])
```

which gives the result

```
-3  -2  -1  0   1   2   3
0   2   6   0   -2  -2  0
```

This results in a dataframe with a column for '0' - that should be easy to get rid of at any point